# EF Core 8 - "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I’m looking for help with Linq query. I want to perform some case-control statistical tests on the population. The results of the tests are stored in a table with some columns like this

```
Id      IMDValue  …
-------------------
1       "2"
2       "3"
…
```

I have an `IQueryable` which filters the cohort and the control population from above table. For simplicity let say I want to sum SQL `RANK()` values grouped by the `PopulationGroup` for cohort+control population.

My code below results in a

> SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

The error happens where I'm building `Rank()` using Linq.

```cs
var cohortFilterIQueryable = cohortFilterQuery.Select(x => new
{
    PopulationGroup = "cohort",
    ImdValue = Convert.ToInt32(x.IMDValue),
});

var controlFilterIQueryable = controlFilterQuery.Select(x => new
{
    PopulationGroup = "CONTROL",
    ImdValue = Convert.ToInt32(x.IMDValue),
});

// Get the entire population - results in UNION ALL
var totalPopulationTable = cohortFilterIQueryable
                           .Concat(controlFilterIQueryable); //ToList() makes below code work but don't want to load results in memory.

var resultQuery = totalPopulationTable
    .GroupBy(x => x.PopulationGroup)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        PopulationGroup = g.Key,
        RankDesc = g.Sum(x =>
            //SQL Rank()
            totalPopulationTable.Where(t => t.ImdValue > x.ImdValue).Count() + 1 //<== This line results in error
            //x.ImdValue <== Simply summing of values works fine
        )
    });

var result = resultQuery.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Is there a way I can do this calculation using EF Core linq? Unfortunately, stored procedures are not possible. :(

Comment: Have you tried to avoid the .Concat/UNION ALL entirely? I am thinking the following approach: `cohortFilterIQueryable.Where(t => t.ImdValue > x.ImdValue).Count() + controlFilterIQueryable.Where(t => t.ImdValue > x.ImdValue).Count() + 1`. I believe it would work, though I didn't test it.

Comment: Issue may be Core 8.  Did you try Core 7?

Comment: I'd use [Linq To DB](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Window-Functions-%28Analytic-Functions%29.html) ORM to work with Window Functions. At least try [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) library. It's on the list [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/).

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is telling you exactly what Linq to SQL is having the problem with.

[image]

You'll need to split the work, unfortunately, into two statements, and process the latter part client-side instead of server-side.

```
var serverSideQuery = await totalPopulationTable
    .GroupBy(x => x.PopulationGroup).ToListAsync();

var tp2 = await totalPopulationTable.Select(i=>new {i.ImdValue}).ToListAsync();

var resultQuery = serverSideQuery
    .Select(g => new
    {
        PopulationGroup = g.Key,
        RankDesc = g.Sum(x =>
            //SQL Rank()
            tp2.Where(t => t.ImdValue > x.ImdValue).Count() + 1 //<== This line results in error
            //x.ImdValue <== Simply summing of values works fine
        )
    });
```

The first statement is going to pull ALL the rows from totalPopulationTable into RAM storage.

The second statement is going to process the aggregation (in this case, a summation).

Performance will degrade with more rows in the source table.  Unless you can switch to a sproc or dynamic SQL, you're stuck with this performance issue.